# Soap XML to PHP

Tags: xml, soap

Hi any idea how I can get the value of DisplayURL from this SimpleXML Object, after try all the comments posted in this site always DisplayURL is empty, any idea could be appreciate it a lot.

Thank You!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[soapBody] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [GetOrderDetailsResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [GetOrderDetailsResult] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QuestMethodResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MethodID>GETORDERDETAIL</MethodID>
  <ClientReferenceID xsi:nil="true" />
  <ReferenceTestID>2102207</ReferenceTestID>
  <QuestOrderID>14706080</QuestOrderID>
  <ResponseStatusID>SUCCESS</ResponseStatusID>
  <DisplayURL>https://esp-load.employersolutions.com/Integration/OrderDetail</DisplayURL>
  <Errors />
</QuestMethodResponse>
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the PHP SoapClient class translates the received XML into PHP objects. Here 's a simple example how to archieve this kind of behaviour.

### Use value objects for your request and response

Normally a SOAP request uses a wsdl address or an request uri, that is defined in the the wsdl. The wsdl contains the description of the webservice. Normally all used data types are defined in the wsdl file as complex and simple types. Since you 're not prividing your wsdl address, I 'm using a simple example, how to use value objects with your PHP SoapClient.

```
class GetOrderDetails
{
    protected int $QuestOrderID;

    public function getQuestOrderID(): int
    {
        return $this->QuestOrderID;
    }

    public function setQuestOrderID(int $QuestOrderID): void
    {
        $this->QuestOrderID = $QuestOrderID;
    }
}
```

Above is a simple value object. It contains a simple type property called `QuestOrderID` which is of the type integer. This is the example for the request. Normale the response complex type is also defined in the wsdl.

```
class GetOrderDetailsResponse
{
    protected int $QuestOrderID;
    protected string $ResponseStatusID;

    public function getQuestOrderID(): int
    {
        return $this->QuestOrderID;
    }

    public function setQuestOrderID(int $QuestOrderID): void
    {
        $this->QuestOrderID = $QuestOrderID;
    }

    public function getResponseStatusID(): string
    {
        return $this->ResponseStatusID;
    }

    public function setResponseStatusID(string $ResponseStatusID): void
    {
        $this->ResponseStatusID = $ResponseStatusID;
    }
}
```

This value object is an invented object. Both shown value objects are not real. I use them for example purpose. You have to find out yourself how your complex types are structured. Just take a look into the wsdl file or use PHPs own `__getTypes()` and `__getFunctions()` methods of the SoapClient class.

### Initialize the soap client with a class map

When initializing the soap client you can use different options. One of the options is the `classmap` option, which defines value objects for requests and responses. The soap client will automatically use these objects and parses the received xml into these objects or for requests it takes the data from the given objects and parses them into xml.

If you want to use the `classmap` option right, you have to take a look into your webservice definitions. All webservice functions use a return type and a type for its used parameters. The `classmap` option takes these types as keys and sorts the given objects to these keys.

```
try {
    $wsdl = 'https://example.com/webservice?wsdl';

    $classmap = [
        'Request' => GetOrderDetails::class,
        'Response' => GetOrderDetailsResponse::class,
    ];

    $options = [
        'classmap' => $classmap,
        'execptions' => true,
        'trace' => true,
    ];

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

The shown type names and the used value objects are not real life examples. Keep in mind, that I don 't know your webservice definitions. This is an example only and shows how to use the classmap.

### Call a webservice function and get the response

When the soap client is initialized you can get all functions with the `__getFunctions()` method of the SoapClient class. It 's simple to call one of the functions now.

```
$argument = new GetOrderDetails();
$argument->setQuestOrderID(1);

$response = $client->GetOrderDetails($argument);
```

As you can see we use the request value object here to set the quest order id. After defining the data we call a webservice method `GetOrderDetails` and take the value object as the needed argument. The soap client translates this object into valid xml. As a result in this small example you 'll get an `GetOrderDetailsResponse` object.

### Important!

To be able to work properly with the PHP SoapClient, it is absolutely necessary to deal with the data types and functions described in the WSDL address before the actual programming. Only if you know all described functions and data types, you can use all the advantages of the PHP SoapClient class. It is not necessary to create requests and responses with SimpleXML or to put them back into an object. The PHP SoapClient does this automatically.

If you give me the working WSDL address, I will show you a working example using the WSDL address.

Comment: Sure here is https://qcs-uat.questdiagnostics.com/services/ESPService.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

this is my function

```
public function order($id = null, $student_id = null, $requirement_id = null)
{
    $url = "https://qcs-uat.questdiagnostics.com/services/ESPService.asmx?wsdl";
    
    $options = [
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
        'classmap' => ['order' => 'questOrderDetail'],
        'execptions' => true,
        'trace' => true,
    ];

    try {
        $client = new SOAPClient($url, $options);
        //dd($client->__getFunctions());            
        $params = array(
            "username" => "removed",
            "password" => "removed",
            "questOrderId" => "14706080"
        );
        $response = $client->GetOrderDetails($params);
        dump($response);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml->GetOrderDetailsResult, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $xml_parse = json_decode($json, TRUE); 
        dd($xml_parse);
    } catch (Exception  $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }               
    die;
}
```

and here is the response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetOrderDetailsResult] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QuestMethodResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MethodID>GETORDERDETAIL</MethodID>
  <ClientReferenceID xsi:nil="true" />
  <ReferenceTestID>2102207</ReferenceTestID>
  <QuestOrderID>14706080</QuestOrderID>
  <ResponseStatusID>SUCCESS</ResponseStatusID>
  <DisplayURL>https://esp-load.employersolutions.com/Integration/OrderDetail?access_token=7d217186-84a6-4151-aa03-9317aab58b2b</DisplayURL>
  <Errors />
</QuestMethodResponse>
)
```

my goal is get the value of ReponseStatusID and DisplayURL

Thank You!